# User online status functionality not working

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am making a django website where users can log in. One of the functionality I need in this website is the "is_active" functionality which basically means
data that stores whether the user is offline or online is stored in the database.
The following is the code which I will explain below:
base.html (the file that is being extended in all pages of the website):

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" contents="'ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'base.css' %}">
        {% block stylesheet %} {% endblock %}
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
        {% if title %}
            <title>{{ title }}</title>
        {% else %}
            <title>Random title</title>
        {% endif %}
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">Website Name</div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="{% url 'common-anime-chat-home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="search-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </nav>
      {% if messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    {{ message }}
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
      {% endif %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        {{ request.user.ID|json_script:"user_id" }}

        <script>
            function updateActiveStatus(isActive) {
                console.log("Updating active status")
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', '/update_active_status/', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', getCookie('csrftoken'));
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            console.log("Active status updated")
                            console.log('Data status: '+data.status);
                        } else {
                            console.error('Error updating active status:', xhr.statusText);
                        }
                    }
                };

                const userId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_id').textContent);
        console.log("User ID: "+userID);
                const data = 'user_id=' + encodeURIComponent(userId) + '&is_active=' + encodeURIComponent(isActive);
                console.log('Data: '+data)
                xhr.send(data);
            }

            function getCookie(name) {
                const value = '; ' + document.cookie;
                const parts = value.split('; ' + name + '=');
                if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
            }

            document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
                if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
                    console.log("Visibile")
                    updateActiveStatus(true);
                } else {
                    console.log("Not visible")
                    updateActiveStatus(false);
                }
            });

            // Initial update when the page loads
            updateActiveStatus(true);

        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the relevant code from views.py:

```
def update_active_status(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
        user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
        is_active = request.POST.get('is_active')
        if user_id and is_active in ['True', 'False']:
            profile = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).first()
            if profile:
                profile.set_active_status(is_active == 'True')
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='common-anime-chat-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='common-anime-chat-about'),
    path('chat/<str:room_name>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('api/get_user_profile_pictures/', views.get_user_profile_pictures, name='get_user_profile_pictures'),
    path('start-chat/', views.start_chat, name='start_chat'),
    path('update_active_status/', views.update_active_status, name='update_active_status'),

]
```

the profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', blank=True, default='profile_pics/default.png')
    biography = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    MyAnimeList_username = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='custom_user_set')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='custom_user_set')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s profile"
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.profile_picture.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.profile_picture.path)

    def set_active_status(self, is_active):
        print("Setting active status to:", is_active)

        self.is_active = is_active
        self.save()
```

I have added various console.log() and print() statements in the code for debugging purposes. The logic behind the code is basically that I add an event listener to whether or not
the user's tab in which the website is open or not is visible or not. If it is visible, I send a request to the view in the code to update the is_active status
of the user to "True" in the database. If it is not visible, then I do the same but I set it to "False".
The following is the output of the JS code in the console:

```
Updating active status
(index):73 UserID: 6
(index):75 Data: user_id=6&is_active=true
(index):64 Active status updated
(index):65 Data status: error
(index):90 Not visible
(index):55 Updating active status
(index):73 UserID: 6
(index):75 Data: user_id=6&is_active=false
(index):64 Active status updated
(index):65 Data status: error
```

I am getting an error in the "data status" console.log() statement for some reason.
Also, I am not seeing the print() statement from inside the set_active_status() function inside the Profile model in the terminal meaning that that function is not being run the way it is intended to.

Please help me out with this problem!